# What does it mean to have a recurrence $T(n) = 2T(n)$

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

I have a recurrence $T(n) = 2T(n)$ that I must find the time complexity for. Although, I have not yet come across a recurrence that did not reduce the problem space like this. I wonder if anyone can provide clarity or insights.

Comment: $T(n)=0$ for any $n$ .

Comment: Maybe T(n+1)=2T(n)?

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given is the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 4):

In the form $T(n)=2T(n)$ it is not a reccurrence, it is an equation true if and only if $T(n)=0$.

A recurrence is in the form $T(n+1)=2T(n)$. In this case every element is twice the previous, thus if we know that $T(0)=T_0$ we can easily find that (can be proved by induction)

$$T(1)=2T_0 \quad T(2)=2T(1)=2^2T_0 \quad ...\quad T(k)=2^kT_0$$